# How to Delete a Column in R?

Tags: r

I'm rather new to programming in R, and I've been wondering if anyone could help me out with this:

I have 3 columns ("females", "males", and "NA"). I'd like to get rid of "NA", in order to stay with "females" and "males" only.

Apparently, this code should do the job, yet it does not:

```
qplot(x = friend_count, data = na.omit(pf), binwidth = 10) +
  scale_x_continuous(lim = c(0, 1000), breaks = seq(0, 1000, 50)) +
  facet_wrap(~gender)
```

Alternatively, this one should work also, yet again it does not:

```
ggplot(aes(x = friend_count), data = subset(pf, !is.na(gender))) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000), breaks = seq(0, 1000, 50)) +
  facet_wrap(~gender)
```

I'd much appreciate if anyone could indicate me what can I do to erase the "NA" column.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `data = subset(pf, gender != 'NA')`

Comment: you should provide your data too. please paste the output of `dput(pf)`

Comment: I feel it is unlikely that you actually have a column with the name `NA`. please share your data

Comment: I suspect base R and dplyr will not allow the creation of a column with the name "NA". So your question and error is not reproducible, as you can see in some careless answers bellow

Comment: We have all been guessing for too long now. You should edit your question for clarity, I flagged the question as needing details or clarity.

Comment: @GuedesBF It's possible to create columns called "NA" using tidyr - see my edited answer below. I agree poster should post data and more code.

Comment: Ok, @Tob, you got me there. You are right, thank you. I still believe there is too much guessing in the answers because the question is unclear, there is no data etc, so my flag stands because, even though you and hello_friend showed me an "NA" column is possible.

Comment: @GuedesBF I agree

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you really have a column named `NA` (which is not a good idea), R automatically adds a `.` to its name. If you want to get rid of the column, just set it to `NULL`:

```
 df$NA. <- NULL
```

In `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
   select(-"NA.")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clean_pf <- within(pf, rm("NA"))
```

Comment: @GuedesBF thats incorrect, see: `df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3); 
df$"NA" <- NA; within(df, rm("NA"))`

Comment: the original df doesn't matter, but one has been provided for you now. You are still incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, i see your point, you are right, thank you. There are some safeguards when creating columns, but you showed a workaround, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to not select the column called NA rather than filtering the columns for NA's.

Something like this should work. Using `select()` from `dplyr`

```
test_df <- data.frame("females" = c(1,0,0,1,0), 
                      "males" = c(0,1,1,0,0), 
                      "NA" = c(0,0,0,0,1))

dplyr::select(test_df, -`NA.`)
```

Also see the below, `tidyr` allows the creation of columns called "NA" when using `pivot_wider()`. I suspect this could have happened to you but I cannot be sure without seeing you data.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

test_data <- data.frame(type = c("male", "male", "female", "female", NA), 
              value = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
               id = c(1,2,3,4, 5))



wide_data <- pivot_wider(test_data, id_cols = id, names_from = type) 

names(wide_data)

#[1] "id"     "male"   "female"
# [4] "NA"

wide_data %>% dplyr::select(-`NA`)
```

Comment: Are you refering to `dplyr`'s select?